# UIBarButtonItem no longer responsive after changing the customView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

```
PO(NSStringFromSelector(self.editSettings.action));
[self.editSettings setCustomView:imageView]; //works if this is commented out but with bad image
PO(NSStringFromSelector(self.editSettings.action));
```

That code produces

```
2013-01-17 11:47:41.184 BadgerNew[29570:c07] NSStringFromSelector(self.editSettings.action): Setting:
2013-01-17 11:47:41.185 BadgerNew[29570:c07] NSStringFromSelector(self.editSettings.action): Setting:
```

So the selector is still the same.

However, after [self.editSettings setCustomView:imageView]; the button can no longer be pressed. Pressing it has no effect whatsoever.

I thought maybe the customView "absorb" the user interaction.

However, I can't set `imageView.userInteractionEnabled`. There is no such selector.

What am I missing?

That doesn't seem to be the problem. I added more console print. It shows that imageView userInteractionEnabled has been false as default

```
UIImage * imageSetting= [UIImage imageNamed:@"setting-button"];
UIImageView * imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:imageSetting];
PO(NSStringFromSelector(self.editSettings.action));//Bar Button Item
self.editSettings.customView =imageView;
PO(NSStringFromSelector(self.editSettings.action));
PO(@(imageView.userInteractionEnabled));
PO(self.editSettings.customView);
PO(imageView);
imageView.userInteractionEnabled=false;
```

I then tried a fully without Interface Builder (IB) solution and do:

```
UIImage * imageSetting= [UIImage imageNamed:@"setting-button"];
UIImageView * imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:imageSetting];
self.editSettings = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithCustomView:imageView];
self.editSettings.action = @selector(Setting:);

self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editSettings;
```

Still doesn't work.

There is someone that says that the customView need to be button instead of image. Well, I wonder.

Comment: What is editSettings? which type of control it is?

Comment: Also, is `imageView` a descendant of UIView? If so, it **does certainly have** the `userInteractionEnabled` property.

Comment: imageView is a UIImageView

Comment: @SharenEayrs then you can do `imageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;`

Comment: I can. I guess I must have messed things up because self.editSettings is UIBarButtonItem

Answer (score 2):

From the doc:

initWithCustomView:

initWithCustomView:

> Initializes a new item using the specified custom view.
>   - (id)initWithCustomView:(UIView *)customView Parameters
>
> customView
>
> ```
> A custom view representing the item.
> ```
>
> Return Value
>
> Newly initialized item with the specified properties. Discussion
>
> **The bar button item created by this method does not call the action**
>   method of its target in response to user interactions. Instead, the
>   bar button item expects the specified custom view to handle any user
>   interactions and provide an appropriate response. Availability